# Java Image array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an app that after clicking a button, will generate a number within a specific range based on a seed (that is already done and working fine) and display an image from an array of drawables. The thing is that I can't figure out how to display an image from `Images[x]` with `x` being the random number.

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quote1);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quote2);
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    int Images[] = {R.drawable.quote1, R.drawable.quote2};

    int data = dateInteger();
    int x = (int) RandomNumber(data);

    int currentImage = Images[x];


    // This is a previous method that I thought about.

    if (x > 5) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (x < 5){
        imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about how to set an image for your `ImageView`, then you can do:

```
imageView.setImageResource(currentImage);
```

Since your `Images` array just has two indexes in it, make sure that your `currentImage` variable (your index) is only `0` or `1`.

Comment: I want to constantly add some images to my array. I tried that line but it crashes the app. Am i doing something wrong? The main aim of the app is to display a random image per day.

Comment: Did you add the `imageView` to your layout? You might want to post the error message.

Comment: Yes, i did. The error message is pointing to int currentImage = Images[x]; and imageView.setImageResource(currentImage); as lines that are causing the problems

Comment: I just found that line: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.palidon.myapplication/com.example.palidon.myapplication.DisplayImage}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=4. Seems like a stupid mistake I made here

Comment: Your random number is too big for your `Images` array size. Your index values can only be `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make array of IDs from res/drawable using

```
getResources().getIdentifier(filename,"drawable", getPackageName());
```

and then

```
imageView.setImageResource(array[random.nextInt(range)]);
```